# Why the Fourier series for this discontinuous function doesn't give the correct behavior near the discontinuity?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, continuity

I was trying to fit some data to a Fourier series expansion, and ended up with the following:

[image]

Why is there no improvement near the gap when adding more terms to the expansion? I was hoping to get some kind of convergence like with the step-function.

Something like this:

[image]

I'm interested in the mathematical reason behind this. Why the approximation near the discontinuity zone doesn't improve?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Comment: yeah I know what this phenomenon is. And it is evident for the square wave at the discontinuity points. But my question was different

Comment: Why the function doesn't even try to mimic that straight line behavior and just goes through the middle? At least for the square wave there is improvement

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question then. What exactly is the data and how did you get this Fourier series? The Fourier series *does* converge where the function is continuous (with additional conditions, see [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions)), so *if* the original function is continuous it's another problem.

Comment: The data are band structures like these ones: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-few-simple-questions-about-band-structure-and-conduction.681656/

Comment: the fitting was done with symfit python's module, using fourier series as the "model"

Comment: We still need more details about what you are passing into the curve fitting: on what interval are you periodically extending this function?  How many terms did you add?  What is the spacing beteeen sample points?  Unlike a square wave, the periodic extension of this function seems discontinuous with a very large jump.  But you don’t seem to be plotting that, so maybe there are huge improvements there (that are being ignored) and fewer at the small jump discontinuity.

Comment: "I'm interested in the mathematical reason behind this." since you know it's the Gibbs phenomenon, have you tried looking it up? It's discussed in a lot of books - in fact there's a lot of explanation in that Wikipedia article that someone found for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't see how this comment adds anything constructive to a question asked 2 y 8 m ago. If you want the OP to improve it, let her know how. Also Wikipedia link was posted, and you tell her to "look it up" sounds snarky to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truncated Fourier series will always be a periodic continuous function. So, the Fourier series cannot converge uniformly to a periodic discontinuous function, because the uniform limit of a sequence of periodic continuous functions is a periodic continuous function. That means that the truncated Fourier series $S_n^f(x)$ for your function cannot converge uniformly. So, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that, for every $N$ (no matter how large,) there will be $n,m \ge N$ and $x$ such that $|S_n^f(x)-S_m^f(x)| > \epsilon$. That's what it means for the series to not converge uniformly. The specifics of this leads to an explanation of the Gibbs phenomena.

Comment: The OP appears to be aware of the Gibbs phenomenon, judging from the square wave plot.  I can’t speak for them but I don’t see any evidence they are asking for uniform convergence, but rather want to see the gap decrease in some other norm, such as $L^2$ or maybe even $L^1$ which is more visually intuitive.

Comment: @ErickWong : The OP asked why the approximation does not improve. The explanation I gave is the reason it cannot improve. Do you disagree?

Comment: Yes I disagree.  Because they explicitly mention the square wave as an example of convergence, the OP cannot possibly be referring to uniform convergence.  It is a narrow interpretation to assume that convergence must be uniform when Fourier series are known to converge pointwise and in norm under various conditions.  I believe that interpretation is objectively inconsistent with the question.

Comment: @ErickWong : It is an error in logic to conclude that I said "convergence must be uniform when Fourier series are know to converge pointwise …" I did not. Read again... It cannot converge uniformly on an interval where there is a jump discontinuity, and that has consequences as I described. You're getting mixed up.

Comment: I did not claim that your answer literally assumes that convergence  equals uniform convergence.  However, without this assumption, your answer does not address the OP’s question.  “Why doesn’t X improve like Y?” cannot he adequately answered by citing a property that is **common** to both X and Y.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @ErickWong : The problem always occurs in convergence of the Fourier series near there is a jump discontinuity in the original function. So, it es answer the question because the series for the square wave suffers from the same defect, whether the OP realizes it or not.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that you have no intention of answering the question that OP asked.  It is very clear that the defect is not the same in both cases, and this is at the heart of the question.